# How to set up printing in android without calling the printManager.print triggering the print_dialog_intent?

Tags: android, printing, android-print-manager

I'm developing an android app that requires printing some photos with a printer
If Using the traditional technique I'll have to call the `printManager.print()`, but this also triggers the print dialog like the picture below [(Pic of the Print Dialog)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7832.png)

This app is designed for a installation art, and the one and only printer is connected to the phone by both usb and wifi direct method
Since the dialog requires user to choose which printer to use on themselves, I feel it largely ruin the user experience, but I have no idea of how to keep track of the connection with the printer without calling this function

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the data stream directly to the printer's port. Or use a custom print service with an activity.